# Mockito throwing a NullPointer Exception testing Service Layer

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to learn mockito by testing a service layer, but

**CarServiceTest.java**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CarService.class})
public class CarServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private CarService carService;

@Mock
private CarRepository carRepository;


@Test
public void getCarDetails_returnsCarInfo() {
    //Mockito.when **** is not able to mock, not sure why.
    Mockito.when(this.carRepository.findByName("prius")).thenReturn(new Car("prius","hybrid"));

    Car expected = new Car("prius", "hybrid");
    //Car expected = carService.getCarDetails("prius");

    Assertions.assertThat(expected.getName()).isEqualTo("prius");
    Assertions.assertThat(expected.getType()).isEqualTo("hybrid");
}
```

**CarService.java**

```
 @Service
 public class CarService {

@Autowired
CarRepository carRepository;

public Car getCarDetails(String name) {
    Car car = carRepository.findByName(name);
    if (car == null) {
        throw new CarNotFoundException();
    }

    System.out.println(car.getName());
    return car;
}
```

**CarRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public class CarRepository {

public Car findByName(String name) {
    if (name.equals("prius")){
        Car car = new Car("prius", "hybrid");
        return car;
    } else {
        throw new CarNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@InjectMocks` won't inject into `@Autowired` fields. Change `CarService` to constructor injection.

Comment: Since this is normal unit test run by mockito, the annotation is not relevant. `Mockito` can inject into fields, if the constraints mentioned in the [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) are considered. Nevertheless constructor inject seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out was importing org.junit.jupiter.api.Test, I changed to org.junit.Test and it worked fine.

Comment: If your aim was to use `Junit5` you should have used `@ExtendWith`.